# Short story about a guy who travels to an alternative Earth where he pirates music from bands that are still together or still alive

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, parallel-universe

This a long shot, so here we go. In the late 90's or early 2000's, I read a book with short stories.

The one story I remember is about a guy who travels to an alternative Earth where he pirates music from bands that are still together or still alive. He finds a one-hit wonder that he sung about his ex-girlfriend.

If anyone has any idea, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: Pretty sure I've read this, but no clue as to title or author.

Comment: Vaguely reminiscent of "[Mozart in Mirrorshades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_in_Mirrorshades)" by Bruce Sterling.

Comment: Bears some resemblance to the 2019 film *[Yesterday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesterday_(2019_film))*, which is about a guy who wakes up in a world where noone remembers the Beatles. Apparently only based on a screenplay, but there are other similar works listed on the Wikipedia page linked above.

Comment: It brings to mind “Mixed Doubles” by Daniel Da Cruz (1989). A failed composer utilizes a time machine to steal music from more talented folk.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be ["Music Played on the Strings of Time"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47230) by Kevin J. Anderson? First published in Analog, January 1993.

Excerpt:

> Other divisions of Alternitech sent people hunting for elusive cures
> to cancer or AIDS, but they had been by and large unsuccessful. A cure
> for cancer would change history too much, spin a timeline both farther
> and further away from their own, and thus make it harder to reach.
>
> "Ghost music," on the other hand, was easy to find. Jeremy wanted to
> find new work by Hendrix or Morrison or Joplin, a time-line where
> these stars had somehow escaped freak accidents or avoided suicide.

In the story, the protagonist visits a parallel world where his counterpart was a one-hit wonder with a track called "For Holly" (Holly being his girlfriend) then killed himself. He considers bringing back a copy of the track then discards the idea at the end of the story:

> Even if he could remember the tune, the words, he could not copy the
> emotion that had made the song so powerful. Such things could not be
> imitated; they had to be felt. He didn't want to end up with a minor
> hit he could not repeat. He had to learn how to do it, not how to copy
> it.